# Onclick pass value to popup modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-modal

I have created a dynamic table and in that table I have a link which should trigger a popup modal.

And I have tried to pass the value to modal popup with "onclick", but the value still didn't show in the modal popup

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
<link href="../libraries/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../libraries/css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="../libraries/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<?php
$sql="select * from tbl_company";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $code=$row['code'];
    $name=$row['name'];
?>
<span id="myBtn" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="getCompanyCode('<?php echo $code;?>','<?php echo $name;?>')"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="../images/edit.png" style="width:20px;"></a></span>
<?php
}
?>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close"><a href="javascript:void(0)">X</a></span>
    <input id="company" name="company" type="text" value="" readonly></td>
    <input id="codes" name="codes" type="text" value="">
</div>
</div>
<script>
    function getCompanyCode(str,nm) {
    alert(str,nm);
    var val_name = nm;
    var val_code = str;
    document.getElementById("company").value = val_name;
    document.getElementById("codes").value = val_code;
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you using so messed up code, messing up with Bootstrap, jQuery and pure JavaScript? Have you used Bootstrap before?

Comment: I am still learning about the bootstrap and javascript, and I tried to learn the material from W3School, but I can not fully understand

Comment: Never ever learn from W3Schools. It's really $h!t and outdated. Sorry for using that word, but it really is bad. See my answer. I am now rewriting the whole code of yours.

Comment: Thanks a lot @PraveenKumar, your solution work great.

Comment: You are welcome boss. Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To open a modal window, you should use `data-toggle="modal"` and `href`. If it's not `<a>`, you can use `data-target` instead:

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"
```

To pass a unique value to the modal, you need to use `data-*` attributes. This can be given to the modal handler like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Open modal for @mdo</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@fat">Open modal for @fat</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Open modal for @getbootstrap</button>
```

The next thing is that, you need to handle the custom input. Once the modal window is shown, you need to execute some stuff. For that, you need to assign an event handler, once the modal window is shown:

```
// Execute something when the modal window is shown.
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var modal = $(this);
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient);
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient);
});
```

---

The issues with your code:

1. Assigning **multiple elements with same `id` is a crime**. Do not reuse `id` as they are unique.
2. You need to assign the `data-toggle` to the `<a>` tag.
3. You should pass the attributes through `data-*` attributes.

**Working Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
    var code = button.data('code'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
    var company = button.data('company'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
    // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
    // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('#code').val(code);
    modal.find('#company').val(company);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-code="code" data-company="company name">
  <img src="../images/edit.png" style="width:20px;">
</a>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="mySmallModalLabel">Codes &amp; Company</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" id="code" readonly />
        <input type="text" id="company" readonly />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please map your code with the above code. You don't need to change any other values. Just the way `<span>` is done.